# Transaction Malleability, if i want to change signature, what part should I change, so that it would remain valid?

Tags: segregated-witness, signature, transaction-malleability

I know what transaction malleability is, but I don't understand how someone can change my signature so that it would remain valid. For example, If I want to change signature what part should I change, can someone explain this to me? or is there some example of this, I tried to find it but failed.

Answer (score 3):

A signature consists of two numbers r and s. You can change s with N - s (N is the elliptic curve order) and it would still be valid.

Sources of malleability are documented here https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0062.mediawiki#motivation